# Как мне одним кликом перекрасить все кнопки

Tags: javascript

У меня есть 3 кнопки мне с помощью JS нужно при клике на одну из них перекрасить все.
Я задал переменную

```
const btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

Я понимаю что нужно сделать перебор и повешать обработчик событий, но так перекрашивается только кнопка на которую нажал.

Comment: дак при клике дай им elem.classList.add('classname)

Answer (score 0):

Я разобрался. Для начала нужно объявить кнопки:

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');
```

После этого, мы не можем повесить для btns обработчик событий, ведь получился псевдомассив. Мы должны его перебрать и поместить в него addEventListener

```
btns.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
    
    });
});
```

Нам нужно чтобы при клике на любой элемент, мы заново перебрали btns чтобы уже задать стили для каждого элемента. То есть при клике на любой элемент, мы должны применить что-то для каждого:

```
btns.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btns.forEach(i => {
            i.style.background = 'blue';
        });
    });
});
```

Теперь при клике на любую кнопку, все кнопки красятся. Если же вы хотите что при повторном клике всё возвращалось обратно, то я реализовал эту структуру через ClassList

**CSS:**

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**JS:**

```
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button');

btns.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btns.forEach(i => {
            i.classList.toggle('blue');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Структуру через classList?...

Comment: @ΝNL993 о какой структуре ты говоришь

Comment: @AndreyFreiz в тексте написано: `то я реализовал эту структуру через ClassList.`